# What are the endpoints oauth/check_token/ and oauth/token_key/?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

The following command activates the end of the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}
```

Now, my question is, what are the uses of these two endpoints and in what ways or places are they used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).

The `tokenKeyAccess()` configures access for the endpoint exposing the public key used for signing JWT tokens.
The `checkTokenAccess()` configures access for the endpoint used to decode access tokens.